# Prove that an integral operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H=L^2([0,1])$ (Lesbegue-integrable in L^2) and $T:H \rightarrow H$ is defined as:

$Tu(t) = \int_{0}^t 4s^3u(s)ds$,  t in [0,1]

I have showed that T is linear and continuous but have no idea how to prove that it is compact.

Comment: Start at the top: what does it mean for $T$ to be compact?

Comment: Multiplication by $4s^3$ on $L^2[0,1]$ is continuous because it is bounded. And $\int_0^t$ is compact on $L^2[0,1]$. So the composition is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: let $\{u_n\}$ be a sequence in the unit ball.  Use Arzela - Ascoli Theorem to show that the sequence of continuous functions $\{T(u_n)\}$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence $\{T(u_n')\}$ (equi-continuity follows by C-S inequality). Since uniform convergence implies convergence in $L^{2}$ the proof is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I know that $T(u_n)$ is continuous?

Comment: I know that the operator is continuous but that does not always imply that $T(u_n)$ is continuous?

Comment: @AndreasNord $\int_0^{t} g(s)\, ds$ is continuous whenever $g$ is integrable.